# Why Doesn't PHPUnit 9 expect the log child element of logging phpunit.xml.dist

Tags: php, phpunit

I am working on transitioning a PHP application (more than 10 years old) to PHP 7.4, we are currently implementing a continuous integration on the PHP 7.4 branch of the application. We decided to use a version of PHPUnit that is supported by the PHP current stable release. So we upgraded the ci testing job of the PHP 7.4 branch to PHPUnit 9.3.

We made all necessary changes according to documentation, but we are blocked on one warning that we don't know how to fix (granted the tests are executed and the report is published at the right place)

```
  Warning - The configuration file did not pass validation!

  The following problems have been detected:

  Line 38:
  - Element 'log': This element is not expected..
```

I am sharing our PHPUnit configuration below and the command we use to launch it, can anyone spot what is wrong with it?

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml.dist


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd"
    colors="true"
    bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
            <directory>tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">api</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <logging>
        <log type="junit" target="build/unit_report.xml"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<log>` element has also [changed](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.3.0/ChangeLog-9.3.md#configuration-of-code-coverage-and-logging-in-phpunitxml) in PHPUnit 9.3.

You need to change

```xml
<logging>
  <log type="junit" target="build/unit_report.xml"/>
</logging>
```

to

```xml
<logging>
  <junit outputFile="build/unit_report.xml"/>
</logging>
```

That being said, I would highly recommend to use PHPUnit´s `--migrate-configuration` CLI option to automatically your configuration file to the new format.

Comment: Thank you i did look if the documentation mentioned any changes and did not see anything so i was confused. I will use the clean then.

Comment: @sebastian-bergmann The link to the changelog is broken, and I can't seem to find information about this in the docs? Am I missing something :)

Comment: To anyone running into this, coverage is now in `<coverage><report><clover outputFile="build/coverage/clover.xml"/>`, no longer under `<logging>`. See https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-report-element

Comment: I just checked: the link to the relevant ChangeLog entry works correctly.

Comment: $ vendor/bin/phpunit --migrate-configuration --verbose
PHPUnit 9.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

phpunit.xml does not need to be migrated.

My phpunit.xml comes from: 
vendor/bin/phpunit --generate-configuration

and its logging section is like this:

<logging>
            <log type="coverage-html" target="coverage-report" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70" />
            <log type="coverage-clover" target="coverage-report/coverage.xml"/>
    </logging>

Answer (score 0):

Changed in PHPUnit 9.5.x

Try any from following

```
<logging>
    <testdoxHtml outputFile="tests/coverage.html"/>
    <testdoxXml outputFile="tests/coverage.xml"/>
    <text outputFile="tests/coverage.txt"/>
</logging>
```

[PHP Unit 9.5 Documentation - Logging](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-logging-element)